# Cannot find property file: resources/dbconfig.properties

Tags: docker, kotlin, hikaricp, ktor

I run a ktor-server app in docker container with JDK 11 and postgres 11.10.
App crashes on start with an exception
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find property file: resources/dbconfig.properties at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.loadProperties(HikariConfig.java:1150)`
I run it with `jar` and if i open an archive, i can see that `dbconfig.properties` exists

[image: exists]

Code, whitch causes expection

```
const val HIKARI_CONFIG_KEY = "ktor.hikariconfig"

fun Application.initDb() {
    val configPath = environment.config.property(HIKARI_CONFIG_KEY).getString()
    val dbConfig = HikariConfig(configPath)
    val dataSource = HikariDataSource(dbConfig)
    Database.connect(dataSource)
    createTables()
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application::class.simpleName).info("Initialized Database")
}
```

When i run it on local machine from intellij idea it works fine

Comment: Does it work if you use the same Hikari code without Ktor?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and fixed it by changing the path from `resources/dbconfig.properties` to `/dbconfig.properties`